# Active Class in Menu when move to div within Section using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm  using `fullpage.js` and a active section menu with it which is working fine and here's the code:-

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section " id="section0">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section active" id="section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Slide 2.1</h1>
                <iframe data-src="auto-height.html"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide active" id="slide2">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Slide 2.2</h1>
                <p>
                    We are using the class `active` on this section and in this particular horizontal slide. This way it will appear on the viewport on page load, instead of the 1st section 1st slide.
                </p>
                <p>You can apply the same logic to horizontal slides</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
            <h1>Slide 2.3</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
        </div>


 <div class="intro page-section" id="sec5" style="background-color: antiquewhite">
            <h1>Normal scrolling</h1>
            <p>
                Eu nec ferri molestie consequat, vel at alia dolore putant. Labore philosophia ut vix. In vis nostrud interesset appellantur, vis et tation feugiat scripserit. Te nec noster suavitate persecuti. Diceret erroribus cu vix, alii omnes ei sit. Sea an corrumpit patrioque, virtute accumsan nominavi et usu, ex mei dolore vocibus incorrupte.

        Duo ea saperet tacimates. Sed possim prodesset no, per novum putent doctus ea. Eu mea magna aliquip graecis, pri corpora officiis complectitur ei, lorem saepe consetetur his ad. Meis consulatu ei vis, an altera ocurreret interesset qui.

        Eu ponderum comprehensam his, case antiopam pri te. Mel ne partem consequat instructior. Ad dicunt malorum sea, ex qui omnes invenire gubergren. Ius cu autem aliquando, pri vide ornatus perpetua an, no has epicuri verterem. Nam at animal pertinax efficiantur.

        Per alienum torquatos eu. Sed saepe quodsi et, ullum choro definitionem sed et. Ullum elitr comprehensam sed at, sint illum propriae per eu. Eu enim laudem reformidans vel. Pro clita quando ad. Usu te virtute quaestio, ut eruditi tacimates volutpat per.

        Affert accusamus duo ex, ea pri habeo graece, cu magna dolorum sea. Quas dictas assueverit ad qui, cu duo harum fabulas apeirian, ullum gubergren et sit. Ne cetero recusabo adipiscing quo, cu harum quaestio neglegentur cum. Has tation aliquip ad, virtute volumus definitionem mel ne. Nobis audiam civibus ius at.

        Ei eum hinc mutat inciderint. Cu maluisset assentior per, graecis ponderum no mel. Eum eu vitae quando gloriatur, cum graece percipitur no, sed errem maiestatis te. Sed porro epicuri te, ad nam malorum verterem. Ea zril aliquip euismod sed.


            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
            menu: '#menu',
            lazyLoad: true,
     scrollOverflow: true
            });
        </script>
```

I have added more content in **section 3** to make it `scrollable` but the problem is i want make div with **id="sec5"** also link to **li** so that when i scroll to **id="sec5"** it will active link just like it does for other section but can't seem to figure out how it will be done i have tried many things and also tried to write custom `jquery` for it but that won't work on it, it would be great if anyone help me out here
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs) states:

> Each section will be defined with an element containing the section
>   class. The active section by default will be the first section, which
>   is taken as the home page.
>
> Sections should be placed inside a wrapper ( in
>   this case). The wrapper can not be the body element.

You should have `.section` as child of `#fullpage`

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

And `.slide` child of `.section`

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
</div>
```

You currently have `.intro.page-section` as child of `.section` with id of `sec5`

So, instead of

```
<div class="intro page-section" id="sec5" style="background-color: antiquewhite">
```

Try using:

```
<div class="intro page slide" id="sec5" style="background-color: antiquewhite">
```

Comment: i have tried using this method but it won't work as it would be a section inside another section.